# Пропали документы, которые поли записаны последние 6-7 дней и база данных выключилась. Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongo

Есть Replica Set( Primary и Secondary) + Arbiter.
На нее пишутся некие данные с помощью приложения на Node.js + mongoose.
Около года все работало стабильно, но потом база просто вылетела с ошибкой, а после перезапуска пропали последние документы.

Как понять что могло пойти не так? Где искать проблему? Может это как то связано с кодовой базой в mongoose? Если требуется сессия, то пишется так:

```
  const session = await startSession()
  await session.startTransaction()

   try { 
   // какие то действия


   await session.commitTransaction()
   await session.endSession()
  } catch(e) {
     
      if (session.inTransaction()) {
      await session.abortTransaction()
      }
    await session.endSession()
  }
```

Comment: а что собственно за "ошибка"?

Comment: @Acinit, Connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: Данная ошибка может быть вызвана многими факторами, банально отключение сервера, моооожет быть на сервере лежат логи об этом, нужно посмотреть и узнать